Adding null check to join causes non-null rows to disappear
create table community(id,actor_id)as values
 (151492, 'https://lemm.ee/c/gameboy')
,(627389, 'https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy')
,(55519,  'https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy');
create table duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id(name,actor_id)as values
 ('actor1','https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy');

With the following query:
select id, c.actor_id, d.actor_id from community c
left join duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id d on d.actor_id = c.actor_id
where c.actor_id like '%gameboy%';

I get the results (where null is an actual null value):










151492
https://lemm.ee/c/gameboy
null


627389
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy


55519
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



If I modify my query to select results that do not have a null actor_id:
select id, c.actor_id, d.actor_id from community c
left join duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id d on d.actor_id = c.actor_id
where c.actor_id like '%gameboy%' and d.actor_id IS NOT NULL;

my results are reduced by 2, to only a single element:










627389
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



I have tried every kind of join. Left, right, outer, inner. None of them work. What am I misunderstanding about joining here? Why is a where clause affecting the join?
The duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id table is created like this:
create temporary table duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id(
  name text
, actor_id text);

copy pg_temp.duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id 
  from '/var/lib/postgresql/data/duplicates.csv' 
  delimiter ',' csv;

This is PostgreSQL 16.

Please show sample data for all relevant tables (as text not images). A script with CREATE TABLE and INSERT is best. Otherwise, cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/_kHS-juP

When debugging join issues, you should execute the query on each individual table and post the results. So SELECT id, actor_id FROM community WHERE actor_id like '%gameboy%' and then SELECT id, actor_id FROM duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id WHERE actor_id like '%gameboy%'

Hm. your dbfiddle (didn't know that existed, thank you!) is making me think that something is just wrong on my side. The whole reason I'm writing these scripts to begin with is because an issue occurred with the software I'm using that duplicated hundreds of rows, and then corrupted several indexes. I'm guessing a corrupted index is causing my where clause to act weirdly here. How do I get around a corrupted index in order to fix the underlying data? I need to come up with my solution before taking the server offline to fix it.

Just use REINDEX: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html

NB: Your WHERE clause ensures that a column from each table has a non-NULL value; therefore, whatever type of JOIN you ask for, you will always effectively get an INNER JOIN.

@FrankHeikens I can't, the index has unique conditions, and the db has duplicated certain rows, so the reindex always fails.

Clean your data first. Your unique index, which isn't unique anymore, seemed to be corrupted.

@FrankHeikens yep. that's literally what I'm trying to do. I can't clean the data though because the query I've listed as my main question is having that behavior where if I put a where clause, rows disappear. So I literally cannot get the data that is duplicated in order to get rid of the duplicated rows, and if I can't get the duplicated rows then I can't clean the data, and thus I cannot reindex.
I think my only option at this point is to delete the regular index and then reindex without the unique condition, but I have no clue what chaos would come from that. I'm quite bad at SQL.

It's hard to tell what the problem is without some sample data, but something must be different than described in the question regarding additional Where clause condition for:

... and d.actor_id IS NOT NULL

If your data is like this:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :  
Create Temporary Table duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id( name text, actor_id text );

Insert Into duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id 

Select 'NAME X', 'https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy' 
-- 
Select * 
From   duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id;




name
actor_id




NAME X
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



--      S a m p l e    D a t a :  
Create Table comunity(id Int, actor_id text);

Insert Into comunity
Select 151492, 'https://lemm.ee/c/gameboy' Union All 
Select 627389, 'https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy'Union All 
Select 55519, 'https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy';
 
Select * From comunity;




id
actor_id




151492
https://lemm.ee/c/gameboy


627389
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy


55519
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



... then your 1st query ...
Select     c.actor_id, d.actor_id
From       comunity c
Left Join  duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id d ON(d.actor_id = c.actor_id)
Where      c.actor_id like '%gameboy%'
Order By   c.actor_id;

... would result as :



actor_id
actor_id




https://lemm.ee/c/gameboy
null


https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy


https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



Null above is Null - not a value, just Null as a lack of any kind of value (none)
The row having Null can be filtered out from resultset with mentioned additional Where condition.
That should not, could not, must not - affect the rest of the resulting rows (not even duplicates). That would just exclude the first row.
Select     c.actor_id, d.actor_id
From       comunity c
Left Join  duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id d ON(d.actor_id = c.actor_id)
Where      c.actor_id like '%gameboy%' And d.actor_id Is Not Null
Order By   c.actor_id;




actor_id
actor_id




https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy


https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy



... The same resultset would be fetched using Inner Join without additional Where condition (IS NOT NULL).
Select     c.actor_id, d.actor_id
From       comunity c
Inner Join duplicate_community_rows_by_name_actor_id d ON(d.actor_id = c.actor_id)
Where      c.actor_id like '%gameboy%';




actor_id
actor_id




https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy


https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy
https://lemmy.world/c/gameboy




Why is a where clause affecting the join?

The where clause isn't affecting the join - where clause just filters the resultset after selection of joined data ... In fact the Left Join itself (the one that is not matched) is the one that put Null instead of d table value in the resultset column ...
There must be something else within your actual context that causes the results you've presented.
fiddle

There is nothing else. All I have to go on is that the indexes are so corrupted that this behavior is happening. I gave the exact data I am using so I'm not sure what extra sample data I could provide. I have spent probably ten hours total trying to figure this out. An example I can give is that if I run this query:
FROM COMMUNITY
GROUP BY ACTOR_ID
HAVING COUNT(ACTOR_ID) > 1;```
It returns only 12 results as being duplicates. 

If instead I run this query:

AS (select name, title, description, actor_id, count(*) as duplicate_count
    from community
    group by name, title, description, actor_id
    having count(*) > 1);
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_duplicate_groups FROM temp_duplicates;

I get 894 results.
